# ACCESS SQL: Nz() Function executed From VBD

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Null to zero in access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705738/convert-null-to-zero-in-access-database)

I'm using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express to create ASP/VB.NET page to connect with a Microsoft office Access 07. Here's my issue:

I have this page with three drop down lists, to be used to filter a DataTable, I have this Access SQL Query that works perfectly fine in the Access, but when I try to execute the sql from VB.net an error is always showing up. "Undefined function 'Nz' in expression."

I've reed that there could be a bug still I can't find a solution.

VB.NET Code:

```
Shared Function SelectFilterWomen(ByVal tTypeCode As Integer, ByVal bBrandCode As Integer, ByVal sSize As Integer) As DataTable
    Dim Command As New OleDbCommand()
    Command.CommandText = "QUERY;"
    Command.Connection = DB.Conn()
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tTypeCode", tTypeCode)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bBrandCode", bBrandCode)
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sSize", sSize)
    Dim Table As New DataTable("FilterWomen Shoes")
    Table.Load(Command.ExecuteReader())
    Return Table
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT S.sShoes_ID , S.sPicture, S.sSize , S.sPrice 
FROM ((Shoes S INNER JOIN Type T ON S.tTypeCode = T.tTypeCode)
INNER JOIN Brand B ON S.bBrandCode = B.bBrandCode) 
WHERE S.tTypeCode = Nz(@tTypeCode, T.tTypeCode) 
AND S.bBrandCode = Nz(@bBrandCode, B.bBrandCode) 
AND S.sSize = Nz(@sSize, S.sSize) 
AND S.sSex = 'Female' AND S.sActive = 'Y';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Access query can use VBA functions (and user-defined functions) if and **only if** the Expression Service is available.  And the Expression Service is only available from within an Access application instance.

When you use OleDb to connect to an Access database file from Dot.Net, you're not connecting to an Access application instance (only its db engine), so the Expression Service is not available.  Therefore you can't use VBA or user-defined functions in your query.  You are limited to only those functions which are implemented by the db engine.

So no matter what you try, any query which includes the VBA `Nz()` function will trigger that "*Undefined function 'Nz' in expression*" error.  Access' db engine doesn't know what `Nz()` is without the Expression Service to help it.

Look for an alternative to `Nz()`.  In many situations, the [IIf Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx) can be a good substitute.

**Syntax**
IIf(expr, truepart, falsepart)

In a query, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT IIf([SomeField] Is Null, "unavailable", [SomeField])
FROM YourTable;
```

If you're aware of the VBA `IIf()` function, this may sound like a contradiction.  However the db engine includes its own implementation of `IIf()` which operates differently than VBA `IIf()`.  The db engine's `IIf()` "short circuts" when *truepart* is True so does not evaluate *falsepart* in that situation; VBA `IIf()` always evaluates both *truepart* and *falsepart* even when *truepart* is True.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isnull` instead of `Nz`. Isnull is the SQL standard function, `Nz` is Access-only.

Comment: isNull will check if the cell contains empty cells

Comment: @user1319587 you're thinking of `is null`; Ben is thinking of `isnull`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Comment: T-SQL ISNULL isn't the same as Access ISNULL.

Comment: @HansUp, User is writing a SQL statement, not a VBA statement. the two-argument `ISNULL` in Access SQL will do the same as ANSI `ISNULL`.

Comment: Using Access' db engine with a query which includes 2 arguments for IsNull() triggers run-time error 3075, "Wrong number of arguments" when run under DAO.  With ADO, the error number is different but the description still includes ""Wrong number of arguments".  I verified this with both Access 2003 and 2007.