# The SQL query of detail in and details out with a four column primary key to generate stock does not match the results in the MS Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Only results for in column `QTY_STOCK` are not correct. Maybe there is something wrong with the SQL code that I made. So if there is an answer then I don't want to use the function in MS Access because I want to use the SQL for VB.Net. Please guide me.

Thanks

```
SELECT  
    t1.CodeProduct, t1.Barcode, t1.Colorcode, t1.Size, 
    t1.ColorName,
    (t1.Qty - t2.Qty) AS QTY_STOCK, 
    t1.Qty AS QTY_STOCKIN, t2.Qty AS QTY_STOCKOUT
FROM
    StocksinDetail AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
    StocksoutDetail AS t2 ON (t1.Size = t2.Size)
                          AND (t1.Colorcode = t2.Colorcode)
                          AND (t1.Barcode = t2.Barcode)
                          AND (t1.CodeProduct = t2.CodeProduct);
```

Results from this SQL:

[image: RESULTFROMSQL]

This would be my desired result:

[image: Tables-Stocks]

Comment: How could we know what's right or wrong? We don't have the table data, or the Excel code.

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms used. (Perhaps <sql-server>?)

Comment: @jarlh , What do you mean by asking for sample data in text?

Comment: You could test `COALESCE(t1.Qty, 0) - COALESCE(t2.Qty, 0) AS QTY_STOCK`, or just `t1.Qty - COALESCE(t2.Qty, 0) AS QTY_STOCK`

Comment: @jarlh , `COALESCE(t1.Qty, 0) - COALESCE(t2.Qty, 0) AS QTY_STOCK, or just t1.Qty - COALESCE(t2.Qty, 0) AS QTY_STOCK` and `t1.Qty - COALESCE(t2.Qty, 0) AS QTY_STOCK` 
I used your solution but there was an error `undefined function 'COALESCE' in expression`

Comment: Are you trying to run that on MS Access? If so, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247858/coalesce-alternative-in-access-sql

Comment: @jarlh , so a replacement for `COALESCE` is `Nz` 
but I can't use it for sql oledb in vb.net because it's a function in MS-ACCESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705738/convert-null-to-zero-in-access-database)!
According to the link above, I got the solution

```
SELECT  
    t1.CodeProduct, t1.Barcode, t1.Colorcode, t1.Size, 
    t1.ColorName,
    IIf(IsNull(t1.Qty),'0',t1.Qty)-IIf(IsNull(t2.Qty),'0',t2.Qty) AS QTY_STOCK,
    t1.Qty AS QTY_STOCKIN, t2.Qty AS QTY_STOCKOUT
FROM
    StocksinDetail AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
    StocksoutDetail AS t2 ON (t1.Size = t2.Size)
                          AND (t1.Colorcode = t2.Colorcode)
                          AND (t1.Barcode = t2.Barcode)
                          AND (t1.CodeProduct = t2.CodeProduct);
```